# Access File from Removable Storage Windows Store/RT

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, access-denied, storagefile

I am trying to develop an application for Windows RT devices. The issue that I face currently is based on the next use-case scenario:

- The user defines a structure named "Song" that has various fields (title, artist, etc.), including an audio file selected using the `FileOpenPicker` class.

I would like to save this structure in a JSON file that contains the provided information (title, artist, **FullPathToAudio**, etc) and load the structure later. After opening the existing songs, I would like to access the audio file and provide a play button.

The problem is that when I try to access the file via the `StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(currentSong.FullPathToAudio)` the application closes. I have checked the *Removable Storage* box from the *Capabilities* tab of the `Package.appxmanifest` file and added a FileTypeAssociation for audio files (MP3).

The Package.AppxManifest file was changed as following:

```
<Applications>
    <Application Id="App" Executable="$targetnametoken$.exe" EntryPoint="JamAid.App">
      <m2:VisualElements DisplayName="JamAid" Square150x150Logo="Assets\Logo.png" Square30x30Logo="Assets\SmallLogo.png" Description="JamAid" ForegroundText="light" BackgroundColor="#464646">
        <m2:SplashScreen Image="Assets\SplashScreen.png" />
      </m2:VisualElements>
      <Extensions>
        <Extension Category="windows.fileTypeAssociation">
          <FileTypeAssociation Name="mpfiles">
            <DisplayName>Mp3 Files</DisplayName>
            <EditFlags OpenIsSafe="true" />
            <SupportedFileTypes>
              <FileType ContentType="audio/mp3">.mp3</FileType>
            </SupportedFileTypes>
          </FileTypeAssociation>
        </Extension>
      </Extensions>
    </Application>
  </Applications>
  <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
    <Capability Name="removableStorage" />
  </Capabilities>
```

Because the user might create playlists with lots of songs, copying the files in the application directory or other accessible location is not an option...

**Edit:** I have tryed to debug the application on the local machine. Now, instead of just closing, it gives the following error:

> An exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> WinRT information: Cannot access the specified file or folder (讠㣯ü).
>   The item is not in a location that the application has access to
>   (including application data folders, folders that are accessible via
>   capabilities, and persisted items in the StorageApplicationPermissions
>   lists). Verify that the file is not marked with system or hidden file
>   attributes.
>
> Additional information: Access is denied.
>
> If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely
>   continued.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that I could use this solution: http://www.jonathanantoine.com/2012/08/06/keep-access-to-filesfolders-the-user-granted-you/

Basically one would have to store the location in the [FutureAccessList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br207457):

```
var picker = new FolderPicker();
picker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*.mp3");
var folder = await picker.PickSingleFolderAsync();

StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.AddOrReplace(Token, folder);
```

And get it back using:

```
var folder = await StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.GetFolderAsync(Token);
```

Comment: Token is a string that can have file/folder i.e. string token = "file";